# Searching multiple columns for multiple matches, based on multiple search criteria

Tags: excel-formula

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VcGQ.jpg)I've been using an INDEX formula to search for results across several columns of data. However the formula's I have (although working ok), are getting extremely large due to the file path of where the data is stored; so i'm looking for any way to 'shrink' the formulas.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$M$12,SMALL(IF(((($B$2:$B$12="All Pages")+($B$2:$B$12="Page A")+($C$2:$C$12="Page A")+($D$2:$D$12="Page A"))*(($F$2:$F$12=E14)+($F$2:$F$12="All Towns")+($G$2:$G$12=E14)+($H$2:$H$12=E14))*(($J$2:$J$12="All Sectors")+($K$2:$K$12="All Sectors")+($L$2:$L$12="All Sectors")+($J$2:$J$12=I14)+($K$2:$K$12=I14)+($L$2:$L$12=I14))),ROW($M$2:$M$12)),ROW($M$2:$M$12)-1),13),"")
```

Is it possible to search the Concatenate'd columns i.e Column A; instead of having to search B,C, & D seperately?

Comment: Have you looked on here for similar questions or relevant answers?

Comment: Hi Solar Mike......i've had a good look; and can't find anything that does quite what I need. I can only find alternate ways to search through the individual columns

Comment: Then you might find editing this to suit may be one solution : https://stackoverflow.com/q/42109617/4961700. What you won't find is an answer already written unless you are very lucky.

Comment: show a screen-shot of your data and some explanations of your current formula will help :)